# bind9 broken after upgrade from 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.9 to 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.10

Tags: server, dns

Good afternoon!

I run Ubuntu 16.04.3 on a small gateway server.

Main services enabled are hostapd, isc-dhcp-server, bind9 and samba.

On January 18th automatic updates updated bind9 (and several related libraries) from *1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.9* to *1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.10* following a security advisory published the day before (https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3535-1/).

After update, dns requests are not being served in the lan network interface. But if you connect directly to the server and run e.g.

```
dig ubuntu.com
```

you get the correct answer.

I suspect this is a regression from the update (no configuration file was changed and dns service was working fine prior to the update), but I would like to check whether anyone is experiencing this since it's working fine when you log into the server itself.